# Simplifying a factorial

Tags: combinatorics

I was given this problem $k(n - k)\binom{n}{k} = n(n - 1)\binom{n-2}{k-1}$ and asked to give an algebraic proof. So far I have simplified to the following:
   $n! \frac{k}{k!} \frac{n - k}{(n - k)!}$
  I know this can be simplified further, however, I am stuck specifically on both denominators. If anyone could take the time to explain the simplification I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks, StarCute.

Comment: $\frac{k}{k!} = \frac{1}{(k-1)!}$, for $k > 0$, of course.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer And is that just because (k - 1)! represents the next factorial? Like if you had 10!, 9! would be the 10 - 1 factorial?

Comment: Not quite sure if I interpret that right. We have the recursive definition of the factorials $(n+1)! = n!\cdot (n+1)$ (with the base case $0! = 1$). So yes, because $(k-1)!$ is the "next" (I'd rather say "previous") factorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to remember here is the definition of the factorial:

For any natural number $n$, the factorial $n!$ is defined by
$$
n!=n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdots2\cdot1.
$$
In other words, **$n!$ is the product of all natural numbers between $1$ and $n$.**

One thing that you could notice is that
$$
n!=n\cdot(n-1)!.
$$
Why?  The left side is the product of all numbers between $1$ and $n$.  The right side has $(n-1)!$, which is the product of all numbers between 1 and $n-1$... and then we multiply it by $n$.

So, you can write
$$
n!\frac{k}{k!}\frac{n-k}{(n-k)!}=n!\frac{k}{k(k-1)!}\frac{n-k}{(n-k)(n-k-1)!}=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:
$$\begin{align}
k(n-k)\binom{n}{k}&=k(n-k)\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\\
 &=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}\\
 &=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)!}{(k-1)!(n-k-1)!}\\
 &= n(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-1}
\end{align}$$
See Daniel's hint above for what went on here. For example, I relied on the fact that
$$
k!=k(k-1)! 
$$
to get from the first equation to the second.